# Would this class be an example of the Builder or Factory design pattern?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I am studying design patterns! I am a little confused about which design pattern this follows. Would it be more appropriate to name this class PizzaFactory or PizzaBuilder? Could you also explain why?

Here is the class:

```
public class PizzaCreator
{
    public CrustFactory? crustFactory;
    private SauceFactory? sauceFactory;
    private CheeseFactory? cheeseFactory;

    public Pizza CreatePizza()
    {
        Crust? crust = crustFactory?.CreateCrust();
        Sauce? sauce = sauceFactory?.CreateSauce();
        Cheese? cheese = cheeseFactory?.CreateCheese();

        return new Pizza(crust, sauce, cheese);
    }

    public PizzaCreator SetCrustFactory(CrustFactory crustFactory)
    {
        this.crustFactory = crustFactory;
        return this;
    }

    public PizzaCreator SetSauceFactory(SauceFactory sauceFactory)
    {
        this.sauceFactory = sauceFactory;
        return this;
    }

    public PizzaCreator SetCheeseFactory(CheeseFactory cheeseFactory)
    {
        this.cheeseFactory = cheeseFactory;
        return this;
    }
}
```

On the outside, the creation of the pizza when using the class looks like the builder pattern to me

```
public Pizza CreateCheesePizza(PizzaCreator pizzaCreator)
{
    return pizzaCreator
            .SetCrustFactory(new ThinCrustFactory())
            .SetSauceFactory(new TomatoSauceFactory())
            .SetCheeseFactory(new MozzarellaCheese())
            .CreatePizza();
}
```

But I feel like inside the class, it seems more like the factory pattern as the setters are not actually building anything, just setting the factory dependencies. The create method then does all the building.

So what is this? A builder class or a factory class? Thank you!

Comment: This is a HodgePodge.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, design patterns are just tools. Not everything that looks like a design pattern automatically needs to be a design pattern.

That being said, I would say that your `PizzaCreator` is a factory which includes a fluent API for configuring it.

A builder would normally have methods setting the actual (future) attributes of the object but in your case, you are setting factories used for creating the objects used for these objects.

At the end, you have a factory where `CreatePizza()` creates the `Pizza` object and the other methods just configure *how* that object would later be created when `CreatePizza()` is called.

However, I do admit that this is a point where the lines get blurry. You don't always have exact design patterns to follow, you should use whatever makes most sense and works best in your use-case.

One could even argue that a builder is generally just a special factory.

Also, I would say that the name `PizzaCreator` is perfectly fine as it is a bit in between a factory and a builder and the name suggests neither of these. But naming is pretty subjective.